# Android Error Installing APK

Tags: android, build, apk

When I try to run my app in an emulator I get the error:

```
The APK file C:\Users\PC\AndroidStudioProjects\AppProject\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
Error while Installing APK
```

I'm not entirely sure what has happened after I just recieved an update for android studio.  I have tried refreshing the gradle projects, cleaning the project, rebuilding the project, building the apk file, and of course restarting android studio.  I can build the apk and it shows up in my file explorer, but when I try to run it gives me this error as if android studio is not finding it.  Can anyone help me or lead me in the right direction to fix the problem?

Comment: Are the APKs still stored in that directory after your update? You might want to make a quick search to find where your APKs are being outputted. They may no longer be located there. It's also possible that the emulator is attempting to read from the APKs before they're even created. I would first try simply locating the app-debug.apk file to see if it is being created somewhere other than the directory stated in the error.

Comment: I gave that a shot and searched my entire pc for the app-debug.apk file but it only came up in the directory it should have been in

Comment: Have you done anything to your gradle.build files? Specifically setting the archivesBaseName?

Comment: No I haven't done anything out of the ordinary.  The project was running and then I updated android studio and it stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey its to do with the Gradle version when running the application. For some reason its not installing the debugger. Just use the version 2.1.3 instead of 2.2.0 and it will work or you can go to  File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Android Plugin Version. change to 2.1.3

[Reference this image if your stuck.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TEAt.png)

Comment: This worked.  Would you be able to source your information please? =)  I would like to know where you got it, if it wasn't yours.

Comment: It was my own work, I'm not on this very much but I found the problem and decided il share my knowledge....

Answer (score 0):

This error can sometimes be caused by issues in your ports. You need to follow these steps to fix this.

1. Go to task manager and kill the service named "adb.exe".
2. If you are using a personal computer , then try switching between your front 
   and back ports.
3. If you are using a laptop, then try switching between your available ports.